# How to get the Apple Javascript Split Flap Counter to run on a local machine

Tags: javascript, animation

I am captivated by the split-flap animation on Apple's 10 billion song download page. However, I have not been able to replicate it on my own machine. I have downloaded the script and what I believe is the appropriate css, but the page only displays 3 images of the number 0. Has anyone gotten the script to work off of the Apple site?

Comment: explain a bit what you are doing.. perhaps some code as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on my system and for some reason the IIS would choke on the `countdown.inc` file .. it would not load it.. i renamed it to `countdown.htm`, and changed the reference in the code to reflect this and it worked just fine...

Comment: For me, it displays just 3 unmoving zeros whether I use the initial countdown.inc url, a countdown.inc or a countdown.htm on my machine.

When you say it worked just fine, does that mean you can see the animation? In that case I am very confused.

Comment: Here is a page i just made with the bare minimum requirements.... http://axristo.info/tests/apple-countdown.htm   (*i noticed that if the countdown file is not loading it displays the three 0s as you mention.. keep in mind that you cannot load it from the apple site since it is an ajax call and it is not allowed..*)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it refused to run on my laptop, but it worked fine on my server. Now I get to tear into the js and make it run backwards...

Answer (score 3):

The script appears to call out to http://www.apple.com/autopush/us/itunes/includes/countdown.inc - are you hosting a local copy of that in the right location?

Comment: I tried both leaving the URL for the call out unmodified, and hosting a version on my machine. Neither method seems to fix he problem, so I assume the issue is elsewhere.

I grabbed the files referenced by the style and script tags, but it doesn't seem to help if I host them on my machine or point them to the initial URL.

The code for my stripped down testing page is here:
http://pastebin.com/m2280b9cf

Answer (score 2):

Someone has built a [nice script](http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter-revisited/) to exactly replicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the animation is all done with a sprite:

http://images.apple.com/itunes/10-billion-song-countdown/images/counter_filmstrip20100211.png

Otherwise, are you debugging the page locally at all? Any .js errors in firebug?